# How do I list all the files affected by apt-get install command?

Tags: apt, bash, dpkg

During the installation of a software many system files will be changed or added to the system. I want to list out all those files that are affected by this "apt-get install" to the system?

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

If it is after the installation, you can use `debsums` with each package that have been install to have the files contained in the packages.

If you want to know it before installing them, I don't know how to do it "easily".
It should be possible to determine what are the packages which will be installed, then do an `apt-get download <packages>`, and run `debsums` on each of those packages.

Another solution could be to version control the directories you want to monitor and after each installation, commit the changes to see clearly what changes have been made.

See [etckeeper](https://joeyh.name/code/etckeeper/) for an integrated solution of a version control of the `/etc` directory